How do I motion track 2d footage from a game with no parallax or 3d whatsoever?
Before anybody says otherwise; I want to preface this by saying I've done this successfully before, but I just don't remember how i did it.
Essentially, I am trying to get the camera motion from footage captured from a 2d game with no parallax whatsoever in it (specifically, line rider) but all my attempts result in the camera rotating in the yaw or pitch axis instead of moving around sideways (without rotation). Either that, or the solve just doesn't work and ends in an error.
Again, I know this has to be possible because I've done it before. But all my attempts to search google and duck duck go have lead absolutely nowhere.
